# RegEx to fix Attribute

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am using the latest Notepad++ and would be grateful for some RegEx development help. I need the RegEx to focus on only the `*` located to the right of colwidth attribute. Below are a couple examples of the XML colwidth attribute I'm talking about:

```
colwidth="0.83*"  (not missing * character)

colwidth="155.7"  (missing * character)
```

The RegEx needs to perform the following task:

If the closing `"` character to the right of the colwidth attribute code is missing the `*` character then I need the RegEx to insert a `*` character so I get this result:  `*"`

However, if the closing `"` character of the colwidth attribute code already is preceded by a `*` character (as shown in example above) then I need the RegEx to do nothing to it.

Can a RegEx be made smart enough to only apply this change to only the text that begins like this: `colwidth="`  And then skip over whatever number/period combination and then only target the closing `"` character and add a `*` character if it is missing it or just skip over it if the `*` is already there preceding the closing `"`?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not a duplicate, and not related to XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's safer to use an XML-aware tool to edit XML. For example, in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), you can write

```
open file.xml ;
for //@colwidth[substring(., string-length(.)) != '*']
    insert text '*' append . ;
save :b ;
```

Comment: Can this "XML-aware tool" you mention make global changes across 1,000 separate XML files? Or does one have to repeat the same operation 1,000 separate times?  That is why I'm using NotePad++. It makes the change across many files as one single operation. Nevertheless, how much does this  "XML-aware tool" cost?  I would like to try it out. Where can I download it?  Does it have a good user guide? Shell applications usually are hard to use. Do you know of a similar app that does the same operations but is in more user friendly Windows GUI?

Comment: Of course it can. You just wrap the code into `for $file in { glob '*.xml' } { open $file ; ... ` or similar.

Comment: Where do I download the User Guide PDF and the "XML-aware tool" app itself? Is it free? Or is there a cost involved?

Comment: It's free. You need Perl installed and its [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML) package. Then you can just install [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2) using any [CPAN](https://mcpan.org) client.